# Logic apps: Create Blob depending on outcome

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I was wondering if there was a way to create a single blob connector in a logic app workflow that creates the blob containing different content DEPENDING on if Logic app connectors fail.

That is (picture to show idea):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is currently only possible via code view.

## 1: Modify `Create blob`'s run-after property to

```
"runAfter": {
   "3": [
      "Failed"
    ]
}
```

## 2: Modify `Create blob`'s run-after property to

```
"runAfter": {
   "3": [
      "Skipped"
    ]
}
```

Or,

```
"runAfter": {
   "2": [
      "Failed"
    ]
}
```

## 3, similar to #2.